# Solving second order non-linear non-homogenous multi-variable differential equation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus

I have got a really weird differential that I have already used half of the whole notebook as scratch but was not able to get the solution. It looks like this
$$\frac{d^2y}{dt^2}=-\frac{a}{x}\frac{dx}{dt}-\frac{b}{y^2}$$
I tried attempting separation of variables, so, I get
$$\frac{d^2y}{dt^2}+\frac{b}{y^2}=C\tag{1}$$
$$-\frac{a}{x}\frac{dx}{dt}=C\tag{2}$$
But I am starting to get doubtful about this, I could not remember applying separation of variables on such cases, but only on F(x,y,t). What is the proper way of solving this differential equation?

Note: Both $y$ and $x$ are functions of t. The differential equation is in its unaltered original form, it does not have a couple. So the relationship of x to y and vice versa is dictated by the differential equation.

Comment: Is that the only equation you have? If not, $y$ (or $x$) can be freely chosen to get $x$ (or $y$). You equations hold, but with $C$ not being constant but $C(t)$, so is, some function of $t$.

Comment: you mean coupled? Unfortunately It is the only one. Suppose it was solve, when we have y and t we can get x likewise if we have x and t we can get y.

Comment: Yes, coupled. I have seen interesting problems with one equation with two functions. They were solved for classes of functions for one of the functions, exponentials or powers of the free variable.

Comment: It does not have any couple. The differential equation is the original starting point.

Comment: Please write $\dfrac ax\dfrac{dx}{dt}$ instead of what you have. At any rate, there's no possible way to solve this, although you could introduce $u=\ln x$ and have $a\dfrac{du}{dt}$. Still completely undeterdetermined. By the way, that's not how separation of variables works.

Comment: I suggest the following interpretation: There are 2 unknown functions $x(t),y(t)$ that are coupled by this 2nd order differential equation. With your method we can find that $x(t)=x_0e^{-t/C}$, However the other equation $y$ from $y''=C-b/y^2$, is a second order non-linear differential equation that do not have a simple solution (but perhaps can be found numerically).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{d^2y}{dt^2}=-\frac{a}{x}\frac{dx}{dt}-\frac{b}{y^2}$$
Chose arbitrary a function $y(t)$

$$\frac{1}{x}\frac{dx}{dt}=-\frac{1}{a}\frac{d^2y}{dt^2}-\frac{b}{a\:y^2}$$
$$\ln|x(t)|=-\frac{1}{a}\int(\frac{d^2y}{dt^2}+\frac{b}{y^2})dt=-\frac{1}{a}\frac{dy}{dt}-\frac{b}{a}\int \frac{1}{y^2}dt$$
$$\boxed{x(t)=C\:e^{-\frac{1}{a}\frac{dy}{dt}-\frac{b}{a}\int \frac{1}{y^2}dt}}$$
Thus your problem has infinity many solutions : For each arbitrary function $y(t)$ you get the related $x(t)$.

For example :

With $y(t)=\frac{1}{sin(t)}\quad;\quad
\frac{dy}{dt}=-\frac{\cos(t)}{\sin^2 (t)}\quad;\quad
x(t)=C\:e^{\frac{1}{a}\frac{\cos(t)}{\sin^2 (t)}-\frac{b}{a}\left(\frac12 t-\frac14\cos(2t) \right)}$

Comment: if the boundary conditions are known for x, is it possible to solve the equation backwards for y as a function of t?

Comment: Can you give an example of what you call "boundary conditions" for $x$.